# JBoss Startup Problem

Tags: jboss-4.2.x

When I start the JBoss server to run my JSP page, it gives the error as:

```
Failed to create directory structure: C:\Program Files\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\log
```

and then a pop-up appears saying

```
Starting JBoss v4.2 at localhost has encountered a problem.
Server JBoss v4.2 at localhost failed to start.
```

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Which Windows version? You may not have access to modify "Program Files" files if running as a normal user. Best to install JBoss outside Program Files, or configure its `data`,`log`,`tmp` and `work` directories to be somewhere you have write access.

Comment: i am using windows 7..... got my answer ... thanx

Answer (score 1):

When starting for the first time for a certain configuration (here being `default`, if they are not already present, JBoss creates the directories:

- `$JBOSS_HOME\server\default\data`
- `$JBOSS_HOME\server\default\log`
- `$JBOSS_HOME\server\default\tmp`
- `$JBOSS_HOME\server\default\work`

These are used to store and write logs, temporary files and other various files generated.

There is obviously an error when it tries to create the `log` folder and this is most likely because it does not have permissions to write and create folders. ( Though you would get this every time since JBoss likes to write a lot of logs all the time ).

In Windows Vista/7, the `Program Files` folder is not (usually) write-able, so an application started by the user cannot create or modify anything there. You could run JBoss as Administrator but DON'T, it's a bad idea. All files which need to be created/modified by an application should usually be stored in the user's folder, Application Data or somewhere else on the hard drive.

Possible solutions:

- Either install your JBoss server somewhere else where you have write access. ( It needs this also when running normally like for storing logs )
- Configure JBoss to store logs and other files in different directories, outside of your normal Program Files one. For example to specify a different directory for logs you can set the JVM startup property `jboss.server.log.dir` ( Specify it at startup by using `java -Djboss.server.log.dir=C:/I_can_write_here/`. You can find the properties for other directories (and a lot more) at http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to check is which, if any, of the directories in the quoted path are missing:

```
C:\Program Files\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\log
```

Obviously, you have bigger problems than just this if `C:\Program Files\` is missing, but you may have other directories missing.

You may need to run an initialize step to validate your configuration and create the directories.